# HTML - Undetectable Audio file

Tags: html, audio

I'm adding audio tag in my HTML file. But somehow download manager showing download panel for downloading the audio file.
[image]

I'm using this code :

```
<audio id="BildirimSes">
<source src="/inc/beep3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><source src="/inc/beep3.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<embed height="0" width="0" src="/inc/beep3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" autoplay="false" controller="false">
<embed height="0" width="0" src="/inc/beep3.ogg" type="audio/ogg" autoplay="false" controller="false">
</audio>
```

My question is, how can I hide(undetectably) my audio file from download manager like IDM?

Comment: The only way would be to configure your IDM not to grab audio files

Comment: Are you sure? I dont think facebook using this way :/ can you suggest like facebook notification sound plays

Comment: I have researched a little and posted a solution that worked for me. Please try it and see if it works for you. Thank you.

Comment: @PrashantGhimire Well how can i use this solution for other users? Can you reach idm conf. in html page?

Comment: did you try the answer that I posted below?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I found:

Download this [**swf player**](https://code.google.com/p/mp3player/downloads/detail?name=player_mp3_1.0.0.swf) from Google :

- Put this file in the same folder as the html file
- Put your mp3 in the same folder

Put this below code in your html

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player_mp3_1.0.0.swf" 
    width="200" height="30">
    <param name="movie" value="player_mp3_1.0.0.swf" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=file.mp3" />
</object>
```

It will use google swf player instead and will stop IDM from detecting the audio file.

[image]

Comment: ok, how can i trigger to on time play it? I used before $('#BildirimSes')[0].play()

Comment: I use this right now but idm still detecting mp3 file for download